# Standardizing sizes across application, but still use `const`

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to standard size across a flutter application to comfort to a 4 pt grid. Here's one example of how this could be done:

```dart
class Spacing {
  const Spacing(double val) : points = val * 4;
  final double points;
}

class PtPadding extends Padding {
  PtPadding({Spacing padding, Widget child}) : super(padding: padding.points, child: child);
}

PtPadding(padding: Spacing(4), child: Text('Hello'));
// or just with regular old Padding
Padding(padding: Spacing(4).points, child: Text('Hello'));
```

This is great, but it seems I forgo the ability to `const` my specialized `PtPadding` forces developers to use `Spacing`. On the other hand, just using `Spacing` in a constructor and accessing the `points`, prevents any widget from being "const"able. So it seems like I have to take a performance hit if I want to implement this spacing in my system.

I could have a class with static const members that point to doubles, but then I'm restrained to the sizes available (ie I can only have so many static members) and I also don't get the benefits of type restrictions.

I'm wondering if anyone else has thoughts in how I might approach this.

For what it's worth, I understand why `Spacing(4).points` is not a `const` (methods inherently aren't consts), but not sure how to get around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you are *extending* `Padding`. Widgets are not made to be extended. Instead, you should use composition.

```dart
class Spacing {
  const Spacing(double val) : points = val * 4;
  final double points;
}

class PtPadding extends StatelessWidget {
  const PtPadding({
    Key key,
    @required this.padding,
    this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Spacing padding;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(padding.points),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Of course Padding accepts `EdgeInsets`. In you example, in the `Padding` in the `build` method is not ` const` though (and it can't be), so do you still get compile const behaviour when using `PtPadding`?

Comment: Padding is not const, but PtPadding is, so that achieves the same thing.